# How to update Git clone

Tags: git

I have started using Git. I have cloned the repo on my local system. I make the changes on the local machine and use `git push` to the update the remote repo. It works fine.

I have a quick query how to update my clone from the remote. I tried `git remote update`. It did not work, new changes does not appear. I just want to make sure I have recent copy of the repo before I get to work. How I can update the clone?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

If you want to fetch + merge, run

```
git pull
```

if you want simply to fetch :

```
git fetch
```

Comment: actually users of my app can upload files. Will using GIT pull create a copy of the uploaded files on my local machine

Comment: @JoshRandall: if your app adds them to git, commits them and pushes them, yes. Otherwise, no.

Answer (score 19):

```
git pull origin master
```

this will sync your master to the central repo and if new branches are pushed to the central repo it will also update your clone copy.

Comment: fatal: 'master' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: I think it should be: git pull origin master

Comment: fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories

Comment: Do you need to be in the dir itself when executing this command or in the parent dir using `git pull origin master <dir>`?

Answer (score 7):

In current GitHub nomenclature 'master' was replaced with 'main', so the command to use is `git pull origin main`

Comment: Command depends on branch name

Answer (score 1):

In Android Studio its VCS then Pull then Master